# Another proof of the iniectivity of a linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, convolution

Let $g(x)= \chi_{[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]}(x) $, and 
$ T \colon L^2(\mathbb{R}) \longrightarrow L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ , $Tf= g \star f$. 
I was asked to prove that $T$ is injective, and I succedeed using the Fourier transform. 
My question is: is there another proof?

Comment: I think the Fourier transform is a good and easy method.

Comment: That's not what I asked, anyway

Answer (score 3):

You can probably start with the smooth case $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$, and write down explicitly $$\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} f(x-y)\, dy =0 \quad\hbox{for (almost) every $x \in \mathbb{R}$}.$$
This should imply rather easily that $f$ vanishes identically. Then remember that a generic $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ can be approximated by continuous functions with compact support.

Comment: Ok, but how I show that $$\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} f(x-y) \, dy = 0 \mbox{ for almost every } x $$ implies $f=0?$
I'm sure it's obvious but now I don't see it

Comment: @StefanoG, the integral is continuous w.r.t $x$,  its differential is 0 a.e, so $f(x+1)=f(x)$,a.e. because $f$'s support is bounded, so $f=0$. a.e